# How to get the name of the route when clicking the back button in the browser Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

When I press the back button in the browser, I go to the previous page, how do I get the route name of the previous page?

Comment: Are you using navigator 2?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh yes

Comment: I use a `AppRouterDelegate` that handle theses stuff, `onPopPage` used to handle back button event, you can check [this example](https://github.com/yeasin50/Flutter-project-Helper/blob/master/navigator2/demo1.dart)